# How do I stop my cursor from moving in vim when executing a :noremap?

Tags: vim, remap

I have a number of these in my .vimrc:

```
:noremap <F1> :set hls!<CR> :echo "hilight seach (hls) =" &hls<CR>
```

(It's nice to have things like autoindent, line numbering, ignorecase, etc., toggled at the press of a button.)

But there is one strange behavior when these actions are executed.  The cursor moves to the right by one column.  If I'm at the end of a line, the cursor moves to the beginning of the next line.  Why is it doing this and how do I prevent it?

This is vim 7.3.429, but I also see it in 7.2.411.

Thanks

Comment: One can also use `:nnoremap <f1> :set hls! hls?<cr>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the space between the `<CR>` and the `:echo`. Remove it and it should work.

```
:noremap <F1> :set hls!<CR>:echo "hilight seach (hls) =" &hls<CR>
```

Comment: Agh!  I thought I'd tried all the permutations of unnecessary spaces.

Answer (score 1):

gpojd is correct the space is causing your movement issues. Perhaps you might be interested in a simpler toggle mappings?

```
nnoremap <f1> :set hls! hls?<cr>
nnoremap <f2> :set spell! spell?<cr>
nnoremap <f3> :set list! list?<cr>
```

Using `set hls?` will display the current value of `'hlsearch'`. Because `:set` can set multiple settings at once you are toggling the value and then asking for the current value to be displayed.